# Meaning of ' send the form through your HR' in the sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

What is the meaning of **send the form through your HR** in the following sentence?

*Simply obtain another subscription form, tick the additional membership column, fill in the other necessary details, attach the passport photograph of the dependant(s) (with name of dependant(s) written on the backside) and send the form through your HR, by post, email or in person to RODING HEALTHCARE.*

The sentence is given in the following link:
https://www.rodinghealthcareltd.com/faq/

Does it mean (1) HR has to send it OR (2) I have to send it after getting signed/attested by my HR? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My reading is that they are suggesting four ways of sending the form to them:

1. through your HR
2. by post
3. by email
4. in person

I guess that if your company is paying for your healthcare, it would be best to give the form to your company's HR department and let them forward it.

Comment: Thanks. I can let HR forward it for this particular case. But I want to know meaning of **send through someone** in general.

Comment: "Send using that person as your agent."

Comment: You can send a letter **through** the post: the postal service is the channel through which the letter passes.  It could, also, as Kate suggests, mean that the person is an agent, ie has a more active role: for example, "Travellers who wish to take more foreign exchange out than they brought in, must apply through an authorised dealer"

Answer (score 1):

The comma after HR means that *through your HR* is a part of the series

> through your HR, by post, email or in person

If it meant that HR (the Human Resources department) should send it by
*post, email or in person*
the comma would be omitted:

> send the form through your HR by post, email or in person.

Besides the comma as an indicator, the HR department isn't going to deliver the form in person, so *through HR* is one of a set of alternatives for the individual submitting the form.

Comment: What would have this sentence meant if it had ended at 'through your HR.'? (I.e, '... send the form through your HR.')

Comment: HR would authorise the application and forward it, along with any others they were dealing with at that time, to the correct recipient.

Comment: @Kate Bunting ok. Thank you. Now I got it.